# HowTo: Detect .Net Configuration Section instance without Loading into memory?

Tags: .net, configuration, system.configuration

Does anyone know how to detect if an instance of a configuration section exists in a .net configuration file without actually having to load the configuration section into memory, and without having to parse the xml file manually - ie, using the System.Configuration namespace.

I have tried using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(...) but this seems to return a "defaulted" instance of the configuration section, even if it does not exist in the configuration file.

Comment: Why does it matter if the section exists or not?  Sounds like your design has issues.  You're attaching a meaning to the absence of the section that should be determined in some other manner.

Comment: The existence of the configuration section determines whether we are executing inside an application domain or not, and a piece of common code needs to make a branching decision based on whether that that condition exists or not.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by application domain, as all .NET code executes within an app domain.  And whether or not a configuration section exists is not, I would wager, a "best practices" way to determine how your code executes.  Bigtime smell here.

Comment: Without going into deep architectural details here, some processing in the system is delegated to plugins with inside non-default appdomains that have custom config. I believe that you are right though, there is a better way of implementing what I need to do, thanks for the poke!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using local config files (as opposed to machine specific) then you could use XML (such as linq to xml) to check the config file by geting the exe codebase from reflection (e.g. Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)